# GCMListenerService doesnt get called when app is closed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

In AndroidManifest.xml I have defined the following components

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.admin.freddyspeaks" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.admin.services.NodeGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.admin.services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.admin.services.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

NodeGcmListenerService.java

```
class NodeGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d("", "From: " + from);
        Log.d("", "Message: " + message);
        //Set data
    }

}
```

MyInstanceIDListenerService.java

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And here is RegistrationIntentService.java

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Unable to register device",e);
        }
    }
}
```

**NodeGcmListenerService onMessage method doesnt get called when I send message from server and if the app is force closed**

Comment: Im facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> GCMListenerService doesnt get called when app is force closed

When app is force closed then it literally means that. There's no normal life cycle calls guaranteed. Your app misbehaved and is now shot down instantly. The system will cleanup leftovers, but your code got nothing to do any more.

PS: inspect stack trace after the crash.

Comment: By force close I mean the app is in closed state and not running in background. Just like when all background apps are closed by long pressing home button and swipe the apps we dont want to run in background. In that case as well I have seen notifications of that app appearing in notification bar.

Comment: so what can we do to receve a notification even when the app is not opened ?